# Attempting to do a flag check with bitwise operators for the first time

Tags: javascript, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

So I'm finally going to try and optimize my code where I'm doing a bunch of flag checks.. I'm trying to start off simple by simply using 8 bits to represent an octagon, I'll have an 8bit number that represents 'used sides' and an 8bit number to represent 'unused sides'

Very straight forward since an octagon conveniently has 8 everything :D

So What I have in javascript is

```
let sidesNotInUse = 0b11111111;
let sidesInUse = 0b00000000;
```

I want to be able to write the following functions

```
function inUse(sideIndex) {
    // checks that the 1 flag at index is set in sidesInUse
}

function use(sideIndex) {
    if(!(inUse(sideIndex))) {
    // operator to set flag at index in sidesInUse to 1 and sidesNotInUse to 0
  }
}

function unuse(sideIndex) {
    if(inUse(sideIndex)) {
        // operator to set flag at index in sidesInUse to 0 and sidesNotInUse to 1
  }
}
```

Not sure if I'm looking at this wrongly but any help would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a **mask** we can specify which bit we want to change.

```
let mask = 1 << 3;
```

means we want to change the bit at position 4 from the right 0000**0**000.

Based on that we can refine your inUse() function to return the
bit at a specific position:

```
function inUse(sideIndex) {
  let mask = 1 << sideIndex;
  if ((sidesInUse & mask) != 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Using the | (OR) operator we can set a bit to 1 while a combination of the ~ (NOT)
and the & (AND) operator gives us the power to finally set a bit to 0.

```
function use(sideIndex) {
  let mask = 1 << sideIndex;
  if (!(inUse(sideIndex))) {
    sidesInUse |= mask;
    sidesNotInUse &= ~mask;
  }
}

function unuse(sideIndex) {
  let mask = 1 << sideIndex;
  if (inUse(sideIndex)) {
    sidesInUse &= ~mask;
    sidesNotInUse |= mask;
  }
}
```

By the way - you don't really need two binary numbers, a single one is sufficient to know wether a side is in use or not.

Comment: I realized that right away with only needing 1 number for the flags. This helped a lot! Thank you.

Comment: So technically the inUse function isnt actually needed.. I could just apply the mask regardless if its taken or not and the results shouldnt change.. right? @obscure

Comment: Well that depends. If you don't care if a bit (or a side therefore) is taken before you use it and set it to 1, you don't need it. ;)
use() will set anything to 1 and unuse will set anything to 0. By the way, you can toggle between 0 and 1 if you use the ^ (XOR) operator.
**sidesInUse ^= mask;** will set a bit to 1 if it has been 0 and vice versa.